# Implementing a Simple Voting DApp on Ethereum Blockchain

Tags: solidity, truffle, nodejs, ethereumj

I am new to Ethereum, Truffle and Solidity. I am looking for a good resource to get started on implementing a DApp for Voting on Ethereum Blockchain. Could you please point me to the correct resource?

Thank you!

Comment: check https://github.com/bellaj/Ballot-Dapp

Answer (score 1):

While it might not teach you how to specifically making a voting DApp, it will give you the tools to make one yourself, which is probably better! When learning I found this to be the most encompassing tutorial that explained most aspects of the project from start to finish

https://coursetro.com/courses/20/Developing-Ethereum-Smart-Contracts-for-Beginners

Answer (score 1):

The following resources might be exactly what you're looking for:

http://www.goverticalworkshop.com/resources/ethereum-voting-app

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3681ZYbDSSk

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

There is a great guide created by the Ethereum Foundation which explains how to create a DAO (Distributed Autonomous Organization). This might be what you are looking for, as it is entirely based on voting.

https://ethereum.org/dao